# Asserting very basic

Tags: c#, .net, nunit

I'm reading content from two files, now I want to test that content with my expected string.

```
string read1 = File.ReadAllText("@C:\somefile.txt");
string read2 = File.ReadAllText("@C:\somefilee.txt");

string expectedString = "blah";

Assert.AreEqual(read1 and read2 equals expected );
```

I know this is basic but I'm kinda stuck here.

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: `Assert.AreEqual(read1, read2);`?!

Comment: no, assert that read1 AND read2 equal to expected strng

Comment: `Assert.AreEqual(read1 + read2, expectedString);`?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use 2 asserts, first to compare expected string with first file content, and then compare second file content with the first one (or with expected string once again), e.g.:

```
Assert.AreEqual(expectedString, read1, "File content should be equal to expected string");
Assert.AreEqual(read1, read2, "Files content should be identical");
```

Or you can use the condition

```
Assert.IsTrue(read1 == read2 == expectedString, "Files content should be equal to expected string");
```

But in this case you won't know what was the problem if the test fails.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use plain C# to write such assertions, which you can with [ExpressionToCode](http://code.google.com/p/expressiontocode/) ([nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExpressionToCodeLib/)).  With that, your assertion would look as follows:

```
PAssert.That(
    () => read1 == expectedString && read2 == expectedString
    , "optional failure message");
```

On a failure, the library will include that expression in it's output, and include the actual values of the various variables (read1, read2, and expectedString) you've used.

For example, you might get a failure that looks as follows:

```
optional failure message
read1 == expectedString && read2 == expectedString
  |    |        |        |   |    |        |
  |    |        |        |   |    |        "blah"
  |    |        |        |   |    false
  |    |        |        |   "Blah"
  |    |        |        false
  |    |        "blah"
  |    true
  "blah"
```

Disclaimer: I wrote ExpressionToCode.

Answer (score 1):

`Assert(read1 == read2 && read1 == expectedString, "Not all equal")`

Answer (score -1):

If I get you right, you want this:

```
try{
if(Assert.AreEqual(read1,read2,false)){
//do things
}
catch(AssertFailedException ex){
//assert failed
}
```

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms243448.aspx) for MSDN.

Comment: If Assert.AreEqual fails, you'll get an exception. That's the failing test. There's no need to catch it.